# 2021 MacBook Pro M1 Touch Bar is completely blank but it works

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, touch-bar

Last night when I plugged in my MacBook to my docking station in my studio my touch bar glitched, flashed white and then went blank, it's black left to right. Despite that, when you try to use it it is still functional, it works.

[image]

I tried restarting the computer, restarting the TouchBarServer, restarting the ControlStrip, both using the activity monitor and the terminal running the following scripts and it is still the same:

```
sudo pkill TouchBarServer
ps -A | sudo pkill TouchBarServer
sudo killall ControlStrip
```

I updated my MacOS system to the latest one, and after the update was done the Touch Bar was working just fine. Still, it would flash white while working, so I reran those scripts following a YouTube tutorial, and instead of stopping the flashlight it killed the thing again and I'm back where I started. The thing works, but it looks like it's turned off.